# How to create a filter condition autocomplete for entity reference field or normal?

Tags: views

I am trying to create a filter condition for entity reference field in views, i tried by using rendered entity option it is showing dropdown for filter condition. **I need autocomplete or it should be without dropdown and autocomplete** (plain filter field).

It should apply after giving full value in filtercondition?

Any suggestions..

```
/* Filter criterion: Content: Cage ID_VBC (field_cage_id_vbc) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_cage_id_vbc_target_id']['id'] = 'field_cage_id_vbc_target_id';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_cage_id_vbc_target_id']['table'] = 'field_data_field_cage_id_vbc';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_cage_id_vbc_target_id']['field'] = 'field_cage_id_vbc_target_id';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_cage_id_vbc_target_id']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_cage_id_vbc_target_id']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_cage_id_vbc_target_id']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'field_cage_id_vbc_target_id_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_cage_id_vbc_target_id']['expose']['label'] = 'Cage ID';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_cage_id_vbc_target_id']['expose']['operator'] = 'field_cage_id_vbc_target_id_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_cage_id_vbc_target_id']['expose']['identifier'] = 'field_cage_id_vbc_target_id';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_cage_id_vbc_target_id']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
```

Comment: @ No Sssweat - Hi are you there?

Answer (score 1):

you can change an exposed filter to **Select List** or **Text Box** using the following code..

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $view = $form_state['view'];
    if ($view->name == 'my_view_machine_name' && $view->current_display == 'display_name') {
        $options = array('your options');
        $form['your field name']['#type'] ='select'; //Use TEXTBOX for text field.
        $form['your field name']['#size'] = null;
        $form['your field name']['#default_value'] = '';
        $form['your field name']['#options'] = $options; //not needed for textbox
    }
  }
}
```

Another option is use **[Autocomplete Deluxe for References](https://www.drupal.org/project/acdx_references)** Module.

Hope this will help you..

Comment: @ Abin - thanks for your response ...where should i change this code?

Comment: write it in custom module and replace "mymodule" with your module name and also view name and field name with your view name and field name.

Comment: @ Abin - In above i have posted my filter code in that place can i change any thing?

Comment: if you want change `field_cage_id_vbc_target_id`  filter.. then replace field name with that in code.

Comment: @ Abin - in the place field_cage_id_vbc_target_id ...your code i want to put?

Comment: no.. you have to put that code in a **custom module**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30423/discussion-between-dine-and-abin).

Comment: @ Abin - Nope,is there any way to do it by module?

Comment: @dine use a custom module and change it to a text field